# Bootstrap navbar is above background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

currently my navbar is floating above my content. [image: navbar]
I tried to make the z-index higher than the backgrounds.

Anybody got an idea?

My HTML:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
```

```
        <a class="brand" style="margin: 0; float: none;" href="#">
            <img src="/img/helmet.png" alt="logo" title="logo" height="100" with="50" />
        </a>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">

            <ul class="navbar-nav pull-left">
                <li class="nav-item active"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Status</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Download</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Teamspeak</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Teamspeak</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="navbar-nav pull-right">
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Teamspeak Bot</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Travel</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Plex</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </nav>
```

css:
https://pastebin.com/5Z5y8YF0
(thanks to Marios Nikolaou :))

Comment: Why did you ask new question?

Comment: I am honest, I am impatient and thought you might not see my comment. Im new here and see that many posts just die.

Comment: it's wrong, update the existing question and delete that the question.